# Как сделать инкрементирование дня месяца раз в секунду в TextView Android

Tags: java, android

Добрый вечер. Подскажите пожалуйста как написать такой счетчик, который увеличивает день месяца каждую секунду независимо сразу по создании метода onCreate.

```
private TextView timeDate;
java.util.Date noteTS = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
String date = "dd MMMM yyyy"; // 01 January 2013
timeDate.setText(DateFormat.format(date, noteTS));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Следующий код будет выполнять тело метода `run()` каждую секунду.
В нем вместо текущего времени, как в примере, вы можете выводить дату в нужном для вас формате. Так же вы можете завести переменную которую каждую секунду будете инкрементировать, в вашем случае так можно изменять значение месяца.

```
android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();
int i = 0;
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
int refreshTime = 1000; // 1 second
textView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        i++; //for example you can increment value there
        textView.setText((int) System.currentTimeMillis()+"");
        handler.postDelayed(this,refreshTime);
    }
});
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь